# After a public API to get 1. the most likely word candidates for the currently typed letters & 2. to get the most likely word for the current sentence

Tags: text, keyboard, artificial-intelligence, prediction

Given all the new AI language models about these days and various OSes having built in predictive keyboards, is there a public API that I can call from .NET to:

[1] Predict a set of likely words to complete the current typed letters
[2] Predict a set of likely words that will appear next in a sentence, given the current words.

This is for an internet connected Windows 11 machine with English as the target.

Comment: The API doesn't need to do [1] and [2]. API suggestions to do either would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this seems promising. There is a ‘Text Prediction’ API. Seems they are also known as text suggestions in Windows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.text.textpredictiongenerator.getcandidatesasync?view=winrt-22621